# Flutter : mqtt topic can only be english?

Tags: flutter, utf-8, mqtt

For my Flutter project, I am using `mqtt_client: ^9.7.2`.

I want to subscribe & publish to a Korean topic and send/receive Korean payloads.

When I subscribe and publish to an English topic, like "test/hi", the payload decodes well using utf8.

However, if I try to subscribe to Korean topics, then it doesn't work.

If I try subscribing to "test/안녕", then nothing happens.

What I want :

```
EXAMPLE::Subscribing to the test/안녕 topic
EXAMPLE::Subscription confirmed for topic test/안녕
EXAMPLE::Publishing our topic
EXAMPLE::Published notification:: topic is test/안녕, with Qos MqttQos.exactlyOnce
EXAMPLE::Change notification:: topic is <test/안녕>, payload is <-- Hello 안녕하세요 -->
```

What is happening :

```
EXAMPLE::Subscribing to the test/안녕 topic
EXAMPLE::Publishing our topic
```

Answer (score 1):

Topics should be UTF-8 strings.

From the [specification](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901107):

> **3.3.2.1 Topic Name**
>
> The Topic Name identifies the information channel to which Payload data is published.
>
> The Topic Name MUST be present as the first field in the PUBLISH packet
> Variable Header. It MUST be a UTF-8 Encoded String as defined in section 1.5.4 [MQTT-3.3.2-1].

---

> **3.8.3 SUBSCRIBE Payload**
>
> The Payload of a SUBSCRIBE packet contains a list of Topic Filters
> indicating the Topics to which the Client wants to subscribe. The
> Topic Filters MUST be a UTF-8 Encoded String [MQTT-3.8.3-1]. Each
> Topic Filter is followed by a Subscription Options byte.

So as long as it's valid it should work.

Comment: thanks @hardillb I tried to do : List<int> encoded = utf8.encode('test/안녕');  String decoded = utf8.decode(encoded); and subscribe to decoded, but it doesn't work.. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: If you are not testing this against your own broker locally, I suggest you set one up so you can look at broker logs at the same time, also look at using an existing client to see if they are able to publish/subscribe to the same topics.